# Does every bilinear (symmetric) form admit a self-adjoint map representation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $Q(x,y)$ be a bilinear (symmetric) form on a finite dimensional vector space $V$, $Q: V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$, is it true that it will admit a linear self-adjoint map $K$ such that

$$(K(x),y) = Q(x,y)$$?

This looks like some sort of Rieze representation, but I am not too sure.

I found this claim in a proof I am reading, but I am not sure if this is true in general.

Comment: What is $V?$ Is it a finite-dimensional vector space?

Comment: @IgorRivin yes sorry, it is finite dimensional.

Comment: It kind of begs the question of how $(-,-)$ is defined: this is extra structure on $V$. So long as $(-, -)$ is nondegenerate (it need not even be symmetric!), any other bilinear form can be written as $Q(x, y) \mapsto (Ax, y)$ for some unique linear operator $A$. If $(-,-)$ is symmetric then it is meaningful for $A$ to be self-adjoint, and in this case $A$ is self-adjoint if and only if $Q$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

A bilinear form looks like

$$Q(x, y) = \sum_{i, j}a_{ij} x_i y_j.$$

The self-adjoint map is then given  by the matrix whose entries are given by

$$k_{ij} = \frac{a_{ij} + a_{ji}}2.$$

Comment: Does this mean the converse is also true? Every self-adjoint map admits a bilinear form such that $Q(x,y) = (K(x),y)$?

Answer (score 1):

Your space has to be Euclidean. If you fix $x$ in your bilinear form, you get a linear form on $y$. By Riesz representation, this linear form is given by the inner product with a given vector $h(x)$. It is easy to see that the map $x\to h(x)$ is linear.

No coordinate representation is needed here.

Comment: Wait why does your argument fail if we aren't on $\mathbb{R}^n$? I thought Rieza works on any Hilbert space?

Comment: It works in any Hilbert space

Comment: you have to assume that your bilinear form is bounded, $Q(x,y)\le C\|x\|\|y\|$ for some $C>0$ so you can use Riesz representation theorem.

Comment: But we are on a finite dimensional space, so it has to be bounded right? So it doesn't have to be Euclidean.

Comment: @Hawk Sure, it is automatically bounded. But for Riesz Theorem to hold you need your space to be Euclidean so you have an inner product. In the infinite dimensional case, you need completeness (so it has to be Hilbert). Completeness is automatic in finite dimensions.

Comment: I am not understanding you. Inner product spaces don't have to be Euclidean.

Comment: @Hawk To me, a Euclidean vector space is a finite-dimensional inner product space over the real numbers.